# Cannot find module '@ngmodule/material-carousel'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm using Angular 8. When I'm trying to import `@ngmodule/material-carousel` i'm getting error.`Cannot find module '@ngmodule/material-carousel'`

**Package.json**

```
"private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^8.0.0-beta.27",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
    "@ngmodule/material-carousel": "^0.6.0", <----
```

**shared.module.ts**

```
import { MatCarouselModule } from '@ngmodule/material-carousel';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    UserLayoutComponent

 ],
  imports: [
    MatCarouselModule
],
  entryComponents: [AppConfirmComponent, AppLoaderComponent]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this. The npm doc specifies it should be used with forRoot() to load at the application boot time.

shared.module.ts

```
import { MatCarouselModule } from '@ngmodule/material-carousel';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    UserLayoutComponent

 ],
  imports: [
    MatCarouselModule.forRoot(),
],
  entryComponents: [AppConfirmComponent, AppLoaderComponent]
```